# How can I run c files in sublime text 3 that takes user inputs?

Tags: c, sublime-text

I am using sublime text 3 for my coding work, but I am not able to build C files and take the user input in sublime text 3.So please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do user input in Sublime. To just integrate a build system using gcc, navigate to Tools > Build System > New Build System and put this in:

```
 {
"shell_cmd" : "gcc $file_name -o ${file_base_name}",
"working_dir" : "$file_path",
"variants":
  [
    {
      "name": "Run",
      "shell_cmd": "gcc $file_name -o ${file_base_name} && ${file_path}/${file_base_name}"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27935037/7431032)

Any other compilers would be similar. I might also suggest Vim if you aren't married to Sublime. [Here](http://www.alexeyshmalko.com/2014/using-vim-as-c-cpp-ide/) is a good blog post about setting up a C development environment in Vim.